# Обработка параметров по условию

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, по Get'u передаю цифровые значения, например site.php?id=271 , на страничке карта таблица со столбиками, и к столбику 271 добавляется специальный css стиль, но как сделать так site.php?id=271,255,260 что бы к трём айдишникам добавлялись css стили, думаю здесь нужна функция explode(), но как это до конца довести до ума?
сам стиль добавляется через такое правило if ($id == "271"){echo "class='select'";}

Comment: Вроде, если передавать как site.php?id=271&id=255&id=260, то \$\_GET['id'] будет возвращать массив значений. Возможно я ошибаюсь, и для php так не сработает.

Comment: Ошибаетесь, но будет работать, если передавать

    ...php?id[]=271&id[]=255&id[]=260

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, буду знать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ids = explode(',',$_GET[id]);
$ids = array_flip($ids);

//ЦИКЛ_РИСОВАНИЯ_ТАБЛИЦЫ
if(isset($ids[$column_id])){
$cssclass = ' class="myclass"';
}else{
$cssclass = '';
}
$out .= sprintf('<td%s>%s</td>',$class, $SOME_CONTENT);
//КОНЕЦ_ЦИКЛА
return $out;
```

Comment: у меня таблица построенна особым способом, типа черчежа кое какого здания)) а цикл выведет его не правильно)

Comment: Ну... можете ручками проверять нужный столбец/строку. О_о 
Хотя что это за особая, <s>уличная магия</s> таблица, которую циклом не выведешь - мне представить сложно.

Comment: спасибо) кое че взял с вашего кода и все работает

Answer (score 1):

```
$rows = explode(',', $_GET['id']);
```

Теперь `$rows` массив необходимых вам значений. Чтобы вам могли помочь с выводом в видах, выложите, пожалуйста, кусок вашего кода отвечающего за вывод. Чтобы проверить есть ли такое значение используйте функцию `in_array()`.

Comment: а как теперь ставить проверку, есть ли в массиве 271 или нету?  
я выложил в вопрос

Comment: Типа того) 

    $est271 = in_array(271, $rows);

Comment: in_array медленная слишком. Не учи человека плохому: флипнуть и искать по ключу выходит многократно быстрее. Случайно обнаружил, когда считал число слов в "Войне и мире".

Comment: А можно подробнее? С конструкцией if else, пожалуйста) Если есть в массиве, то ставим класс class='select', если нету то нету)

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вы "подсвечиваете" строки, объекты в которых находятся в каком-то особом для Вас состоянии. Почему бы не хранить флаг этого состояния в БД? Вы ведь чувствуете, что передавать через GET к примеру 100 значений это совсем не вариант?

Comment: через гет передаются максимум 3 значения, в моем случаи) и больше быть не может

Comment: Тогда explode(',',$_GET[id]); решит вопрос на ура.